# Eclipse rcp export resource file as file

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have a simple ini file inside my plugin under **config/config.ini**.

When I export the product I need this file inside the product's own file structure so another program can read and write it.

And by the file structure I mean the directory where my eclipse.exe resides.

At the same time I need it inside my Eclipse RCP application too.

Here is the file:

[image]

And here is the output of the export where I need it to show up (or in any subfolder):

[image]

Is there any way to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify extra files to be added to the root directory of the build using the `build.properties` of any of the `features` in your product (you do need to use features for this)

The simplest would be

```
root=file:config.ini
```

For this you would have to put the `config.ini` in the same directory as the feature `build.properties`

For more details see [Adding Files to the Root of a Build](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.pde.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fpde_rootfiles.htm) in the help.